# AS3 - Encoding and Exporting Multiple jpegs from Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I currently have a flash (AS3) project which consists of a sketchpad onto which users can draw content. I would like to record this drawn content as a series of jpeg screenshots and have placed a "record" and "stop" button by the drawing area. I'm trying to get the code below to achieve the following:

1) When "record" is pressed, 15 screenshots (Bitmaps) should be captured and stored in the "jpgSource" array for up to one minute.

2) When "stop" is pressed, the function taking screenshots should stop, all of the bitmaps stored in jpgSource should be converted to jpegs, and all of the jpegs should be exported to a php handler.

Currently, when I run this code, the php code spits out only a single jpeg image (the last one taken). I'd be incredibly grateful if someone could point out where I'm going wrong.

**EDIT: I've discovered that NavigateToUrl can only function once per frame, explaining the error I keep encountering. I read here (http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=250594) that a timer can be used to bypass this problem, but I'm not quite sure how to implement one in this case. I'd be very grateful for any advice, as always.**

```
var sourceArray:Array = [];

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(50,200);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void {
var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (850, stage.height);
jpgSource.draw(stage);
sourceArray.push(jpgSource);        
}

recordbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, recordbuttonClick);
stopbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopbuttonClick);

function recordbuttonClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
{   
myTimer.start();
}


function stopbuttonClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
myTimer.stop();
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(50);
    for (var i:Number=1; i<sourceArray.length; i++){
    var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(sourceArray[i]);
    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("imageprocess.php?name=drawing.jpg");
    jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
    jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
    navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "blank");
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] ) && isset ( $_GET['name'] ) ) {

//the image file name
$fileName = time();

// get the binary stream
$im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

//write it
$fp = fopen($fileName, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $im);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: name=drawing.jpg is this the name you are using to save the image in the server? If so, then you overriding the the last image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/wiki/MultipartURLLoader

Pay attention to this link. It allow to upload several images per single request.

===============

Usage:

http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=139

Comment: Thanks very much for this link. I've downloaded the test files and .as classes but can't seem to get the test project to work. Any idea how I'd be able to integrate this class into my code? Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed right off-hand is that there is no closure bracket `}` on your last `for` statement. Is this a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: @Larusso has a point. Try: `"imageprocess.php?name=drawing_" + i + ".jpg"`

Comment: Great catch (thanks to you too, @larusso). I've adjusted that line per your suggestion but the end result is still the same. It seems that the "image process.php" code is accessed only once, and only the final screenshot is saved. Could this be a problem with my php code? If so, I'd be happy to post. Thanks so much for all of your help -- I really appreciate it!

Comment: I've posted the php code I'm using above, just as a reference. I've adjusted it to name each image according to a time()stamp, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a long time ago now since you asked: just change the initial value of i to 0 and eve